# Sentence structure with wo

Tags: word-order

I wanted to write:

> Can you please tell me where can I find you?

so I wrote:

> Können Sie mir bitte sagen, wo kann ich Sie finden?

I have two questions: The most important one - should I write

> ..., wo kann ich **or** ...,wo ich kann

I guess the question is does *wo* introduce a Nebensatz.

The other one is can I interchange the **mir** and the **bitte**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in that your question introduces a subordinate clause (*Nebensatz*), but as such you need to follow the subordinate clause word order which is verb last. Thus, the correct sentence is:

> Können Sie mir bitte sagen, *wo ich Sie finden kann?*

To me as a native speaker it would sound wrong to switch the positions of *mir* and *bitte*. I would stick to *können Sie mir bitte*, although I'm not entirely sure if it would count as wrong.